# regex for picking last one from text

Tags: regex

Edit: my bad that I didn't explained it properly.

So my question is that I have text string which can look like anything and will have attach [ATTACH]**[ATTACH] text in between and in last of that text but now what I want is only  select the last one either it exists or not it should not select in between the text it should always had to be in last.
 what im trying is to select the last one

`[ATTACH]36[ATTACH]`

without selecting the any one from below text

```
Gdfhbghuhcghbhhijb
    [ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]
    [ATTACH]36[ATTACH]
    foo
    bar
    foo
    bar
    foo
    foobar foobaz [ATTACH]36[ATTACH]
```

i had tried a lot on regex sites but always failed so can anyone tell how to do it with regex

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: your question is not clear please explain

Comment: how does it matter to pick the last one if both first one and last one look same?

Comment: What's your criteria for matching or not? Do you always want the last `[ATTACH=full]` element? Or only if it's `36`? Or always the 2nd-to-last `[ATTACH]`? Explain.

Comment: Well now I had updated my question with proper description.

Comment: @BrianStephens yes i always want the last [ATTACH] element. foobar foobaz "[ATTACH]36[ATTACH]". the word in the quotes only. and the no 36 may vary but "attach" will remain same throughout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?sim)(?:\[ATTACH=full\]36\[ATTACH\])(?!.*?(?:\[ATTACH=full\]36\[ATTACH\]))
```

You can check [here](https://regex101.com/r/QZLXWg/3)

Comment: sorry it's my bad that I had not explained it properly can you look onto it now

Answer (score 0):

update after question edit, following should work:

```
(\[ATTACH]\d+\[ATTACH])(?!.*\[ATTACH]\d+\[ATTACH])
```

following regex match exactly the last `[ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]`

```
(\[ATTACH=full]36\[ATTACH])(?!.*\1)
```

depending on language flag `/s` must be set to specify `.` matches also `\n`

Perl example :

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say for /(\[ATTACH=full]36\[ATTACH])(?!.*\1)/gs' <<END
[ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]
  [ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]
  [ATTACH]36[ATTACH]
  [ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]
  [ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]
  [ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]
  [ATTACH]36[ATTACH]
  foo
  bar
  foo
  bar
  foo
  foobar foobaz
END

[ATTACH=full]36[ATTACH]
```

Comment: Hi really thanks it works like i had asked though was my mistake that I didn't explained it properly , though can please look on into that again .

Comment: i want to check only if exist in last line i.e after foobaz, other wise it should not select any.